# Naming elements - best practices

Tags: css, naming-conventions

When it comes to naming elements, should I use 'class' names for CSS & 'id' names for JS?
 Is there a different rule of thumb? Should I just use one name? 
Any insights/suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a little more complicated than simply going with `class` and/or `id` for your naming conventions. 
In fact, JavaScript and CSS should be handled in very different ways as far as naming and identifying elements. I'd recommend checking out [this guide on beginning CSS](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/30-css-best-practices-for-beginners--net-6741) or if you want to challenge yourself and build styles that are really versatile and reusable, check out [this article on semantic class names](http://css-tricks.com/semantic-class-names/) or [Meduim's CSS is Actually Pretty F***n good](https://medium.com/@fat/mediums-css-is-actually-pretty-fucking-good-b8e2a6c78b06) by @fat (one of the guys who made the [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) lib)

Note that these are opinions and you have a lot of freedom with CSS, it's about being creative, but also making something that if you died someone else could understand and leverage your code.

JavaScript is something that can more easily turn into a mess if you don't follow some good practices, I'd check out some of the links at the bottom of this post, but the important thing is that you are consistent, verbose, and use comments and tests. In regards to naming HTML elements for manipulating them, if you are ***sure*** that you will only have **one** element per page that you want to perform certain actions with (for example a username field on a login form) than an `Id` is acceptable and makes sense, so long as the naming is consistent (for example: don't call your username field on a login form `id="name"` as that could be misconstrued, instead call it `id="username"` or `id="login-username"`) making a name clear doesn't waste a significant enough amount of memory and network bandwidth to replace all the headaches a future developer could have trying to figure out what is going on with the id's and classes.

When it makes sense to use a class for identifying a collection of elements in your page via javascript - make a point to use a classname specifically for your javascript - perhaps prefix it with `js-<classname>` or make it a stateful name such as `is-selected` so that you 1) know when looking at it that it might be something that could be useful to manipulate in javascript code, and 2) so that it doesn't get confused or convoluted with your styles in your CSS.

In short your goal should be to have consistency and clarity in your naming - sometimes it might mean an `id`(when you only want there to be one of something on a page) and other times it might be a `class`(when there may or may not be many of them on a page) - just be thoughtful of whether it would make sense to someone looking at it for the first time.

link dump:

- [opinion 1 on js variable naming](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/variable-naming-conventions-in-javascript.html)
- [opinion 2](http://www.w3.org/wiki/JavaScript_best_practices)
- [opinion 3](https://github.com/stevekwan/best-practices/blob/master/javascript/best-practices.md)

note there are tons of opinions out there - again its more important to be consistent rather than whatever people say is the best practice for the year (but you will find that people tend to follow some naming basics such as all caps for constants and camelCase for javascript variables, etc.) - read up, pick what you like and go with it.